# Android - layoutopt fails

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the layoutopt (from the SDK) on the layouts in my project.

Every time I'm running the layoutopt on a layout which has in it 'android:layout_weight' somewhere, I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
        at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.getAt(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2794)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$213.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:44)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at Script5.run(Script5.groovy:15)
        at com.android.layoutopt.uix.rules.GroovyRule$1.call(GroovyRule.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:105)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:212)
        at com.android.layoutopt.uix.rules.GroovyRule.run(GroovyRule.java:65)
        at com.android.layoutopt.uix.LayoutAnalyzer.applyRules(LayoutAnalyzer.java:246)
        at com.android.layoutopt.uix.LayoutAnalyzer.analyze(LayoutAnalyzer.java:233)
        at com.android.layoutopt.uix.LayoutAnalyzer.analyze(LayoutAnalyzer.java:238)
        at com.android.layoutopt.uix.LayoutAnalyzer.analyze(LayoutAnalyzer.java:221)
        at com.android.layoutopt.uix.LayoutAnalyzer.analyze(LayoutAnalyzer.java:153)
        at com.android.layoutopt.uix.LayoutAnalyzer.analyze(LayoutAnalyzer.java:128)
        at com.android.layoutopt.cli.Main.analyze(Main.java:61)
        at com.android.layoutopt.cli.Main.analyzeFiles(Main.java:53)
        at com.android.layoutopt.cli.Main.main(Main.java:46)
```

Any one has idea why this is happening?

Comment: Have you add the attribute android:weightSum to the parent layout?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I found the problem, schemes problem. I'll show the the example at the moment I'll be able to post (low reputation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I found my problem.

In the layout I had 2 schemes pointing to the same place:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:layout_width="321dp" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know how did it happen, probably bug or something, I didn't write it.
Anyway, This caused the layoutopt to fail.

Thank you for trying helping